# How to display all available variants in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have this simple code, how can I display all available variants ?

```
#Display all possible variants until reach input sum with coins of 2 and 5
#Not fixed: Output only first result !

#Input
summ = int(input("Enter sum: "))
two = 2
five = 5

#Calculations/Checks/Output
for i in range(0, two+1):
    for j in range(0, five+1):
        if (i*2 + j*5 == summ):
            print(i, "*2 + ", j, "*5 = ", summ)

#End
```

For example:

```
Input: 17

Output:
1*2 + 3*5 = 17
6*2 + 1*5 = 17
```

But the code displays only the first result?
How can I fix this ?

Comment: Because you're ranges are not correct. (6 is out of those range)

Comment: `two = 2` this line is only missing the comment `# set two to 2` (More seriously, using variables instead of "magic numbers" in your code is good, but consider using a more meaningful name, like `number_of_two_dollar_coins`)

Comment: Your code only shown the first result because `6*2` is not a valid solution. With `two = 2`, there can be at max `2*2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the inputs of `range`:

```
summ = int(input("Enter sum: "))
two = 2
five = 5

for i in range(summ//two+1):
    for j in range(summ//five+1):
        if (i*2 + j*5 == summ):
            print(i, "* 2 +", j, "* 5 =", summ)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools, and a generator:

```
In [17]: def correct_sum_i(i, val):
    ...:     sum_perm = [comb for comb in itertools.combinations_with_replacement([2,5],i) if sum(comb) == val]
    ...:     return sum_perm[0] if sum_perm else None
    ...: 

In [18]: val = 14

In [19]: next(correct_sum_i(i,val) for i in range(1000) if correct_sum_i(i, val))
Out[19]: (2, 2, 5, 5)
```

Edit: You probably also want to check for pathological cases where this is not possible, like 1,3 etc....

Edit: all sums

```
In [50]: def all_sums(char_set, sum_value):
    ...:     def correct_sum_i(i):
    ...:         
    ...:         sum_perm = [comb for comb in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(char_set,i) if sum(comb) == sum_value]
    ...:         return sum_perm if sum_perm else None
    ...:     
    ...:     assert min(char_set)  > 0
    ...:     
    ...:     return list(correct_sum_i(i) for i in range(int(sum_value / min(char_set))+ 1) if correct_sum_i(i))
    ...: 

In [51]: print (all_sums([2,5], 20))
[[(5, 5, 5, 5)], [(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5)], [(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)]]
```

this also gives you the desired behaviour for your case:

```
In [53]: print (all_sums([2,5], 17))
[[(2, 5, 5, 5)], [(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5)]]
```